# For each node v: find the cheaper colorful path from s to v

Tags: algorithms

Let $\ G = (V,E)$ where each node has one of three colors $\ {R, G, B}$. 

 A path (not necessarily simple) will be called colorful if it contains all the colors. 
**Input**: directed Graph G as above (including the color of each node), $\ s∈V$, and positive weights $\ w: E → Q$.
**Output**: For each node $\ v$ : find the cheaper colorful path (not necessarily simple) from $\ s$ to $\ v$ (if none exists then return infinity).

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Comment: I know I should use Daijkstra algorithm and duplicate graph but I don't know how to continue. Also I don't know how to edit question body. thank u @saulspatz

Comment: You can edit [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3514941/edit)

Comment: now? @saulspatz